# Vercel not sending email

Tags: sendgrid, vercel, sveltekit

I use SendGrid and I know my SendGrid-API key is working by checking from a terminal.
I verified my email in SendGrid Sender Identity.

```
curl -i --request POST \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer MY-API-KYE_HERE' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "myname@gmail.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "connect@mywebsite.com"},"subject": "SendGrid Test!","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Howdy!"}]}'
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 20 Dec 2021 04:42:08 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Message-Id: 9G5w8P8_SJWPwj1acrNRPQ
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains
```

And I get an email.

It works on localhost as well.

But when I deploy to Vercel with the following code, it won't send any email.

```
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const host = process.env['HOST_URL']
const email_from = process.env['EMAIL_FROM']
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = process.env['SENDGRID_API']

export const sendGridConfirmationEmail = async (name, email, confirmationCode) => {
  await sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY)
  const msg = {
    to: email,
    from: `${email_from}`,
    subject: "Please confirm your account",
    text: `Email Confirmation: Hello ${name}.
    Please confirm your email by clicking on the following link.
    Click here, ${host}/auth/confirm/${confirmationCode}`,
    html:`<h1>Email Confirmation</h1>
    <h2>Hello ${name}</h2>
    <p>Please confirm your email by clicking on the following link.</p>
    <a href=${host}/auth/confirm/${confirmationCode}> Click here</a>
    </div>`,
  }
  await sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Email sent')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}
```

I tried the following too, but not working either.

```
export const sendGridConfirmationEmail = async (name, email, confirmationCode) => {
   await fetch(SENDGRID_API, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       Authorization: `Bearer ${SENDGRID_API_KEY}`
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       personalizations: [
         {
           to: [
             {
               email
             }
           ],
           subject: 'Demo success :)'
         }
       ],
       from: {
         email: email_from,
         name: 'Test SendGrid'
       },
       content: [
         {
           type: 'text/html',
           value: `Congratulations <b>${name}</b>, you just sent an email with sendGrid. ${confirmationCode}`
         }
       ]
     })
 });
}
```

How can I send email from Vercel using SendGrid?

Comment: Vercel timeout is 5 secs for a function may be it gets dropped before it completes the execution so it not able to send email

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.

When I call `sendGridConfirmationEmail`, I need to use `await`.

```
export const post = async ({ body }) => {
...

 if (mail_method === "sendgrid") {
    await sendGridConfirmationEmail(
      body.name,
      body.email,
      token
    );
      console.log('SendGrid registration is emailed.')
  }
...
```